# loggers and logging in nodejs what is should be like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, backend, node-modules

I'm studying the loggers and logging subject for first time.. and I'm trying to create it via nodejs application after watching some tutorials .

after I did it I found all tutorials that do it in index.js file .. it's smth like

```
logger.warn('text warn')
logger.error('text error')
logger.error(new Error('smth wrong here'))
```

but what I studied was I should print system logs, if it has warn or any issues.
how can I do it? and if I want to save these details in text file it will be better?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume you would like to know how to use a logger module.

I'm using [winston](http://npmjs.com/package/winston). It is fairly easy to use and the documentation is very clear.
All you need is to create your own `logger` which is done by using the `createLogger` function. There're many options you can use to configure your `logger` so you will just need to read the documentation.

Here is an example of how I use it in my projects, exporting the `logger` and then using it in the app:

logger.js:

```
const { addColors, transports, format, createLogger } = require("winston");
const { combine, colorize, simple, prettyPrint } = format;

const logLevels = {
  levels: { critical: 0, error: 1, warning: 2, debug: 3, info: 4 },
  colors: {
    critical: "bold magenta",
    error: "bold red",
    warning: "bold yellow",
    info: "bold blue",
    debug: "bold green",
  },
};

addColors(logLevels.colors);

const transport =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? new transports.Console({
        format: combine(colorize(), simple()),
      })
    : new transports.File({ filename: "file.log" });

const logger = createLogger({
  levels: logLevels.levels,
  format: prettyPrint(),
  transports: [transport],
});

module.exports = logger;
```

app.js:

```
const logger = require("./logger");
logger.log({ level: "info", message: "info log" });
```

Comment: my question exactly in this part :
const logger = require("./logger");
logger.log({ level: "info", message: "info log" });
 in => logger.log({ level: "info", message: "info log" });
can I save actual info and message became with a real message from the system ? not from my own?

Comment: Sure. for example, Let's say you have an `express` server and you want to log all the requests coming into `/example` POST route. The `/example` POST route will look something like: 

app.post("/example", (req, res) => {
  logger.log({ level: "info", message: req.body });
  res.status(200).send("logger example");
});

Comment: nice !! what about errors and other types of loggers? how can save it?

Comment: another question, when i add your example I get message as {} -empty- how I can fix it ?

Comment: You can log errors the same way you log any object. let's say you have a `promise`, in your `.catch` block you can do something like `.catch((err) => {logger.log({ level: "error", message: err }); });`.
regarding my example. you need to have something sent in the request as the body.

Comment: what exactly i did is     logger.log({ level: "info",   message: "get user from db" });;
but it's still empty..

Comment: Check if you actually get something from the db...

Comment: yep yep!! thanks a lot, it's working!